# Eigenvalues of symmetric complex matrices .

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that for symmetric matrix with complex entries all eigenvalues are real.

I have seen the proof for Hermitian matrices and proved it for real symmetric matrices,but for complex symmetric matrices I dont know how to determine this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hint: Try a 2x2 matrix where all entries = $i$.

Comment: This is true for self-adjoint matrices, aka hermitian matrices. Not for symmetric matrices. Look at $\left(\matrix{0&i\\i&0}\right)$ for instance.

Comment: @julien: easier example than mine! Regards

Comment: How about $\begin{bmatrix} i \end{bmatrix}$. No simpler than that!

Comment: @copper.hat: Nice example!

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered in the comments; this is a community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered.

The answer is no; symmetric matrices with complex entries do not in general have real eigenvalues.